# Who is the doer when we use the verb 崩す?

Tags: grammar

崩す is a transitive verb so it should have a doer(omitted or not)

In this sentence, the doer seems to be 彼, he destroyed himself with alcohol:

> 酒で彼は身を崩した。 Drink brought about his downfall.

But in the following sentence, it doesn't work well to say that 彼 is the doer since it seems that he is not voluntarily ill:

> 彼は少し体調を崩して, 今週は学校を休んでいる. He has been off school with a slight illness
>   this week.

Is the doer omitted in this sentence? If yes, is a sentence like 彼は風邪が体調を崩す correct to say that he is ill because of a cold?

I don't find any occurrence on google search so I think it is not natural but I don't know why in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「彼{かれ}は少{すこ}し体調{たいちょう}を崩{くず}して, 今週{こんしゅう}は学校{がっこう}を休{やす}んでいる。」

Without a doubt, the subject/doer of the verb phrase 「体調を崩す」 would be 「彼」, but that is not to say that 「彼」 voluntarily chose to become ill.  You might have to forget the translated English word "destroy" here because that could fool you in your attempt to determine the "doer".

「彼」 is the subject/doer of both actions 「体調を崩す」 and 「学校を休む」 in this sentence.  There is no unmentioned subject/doer here.

> "He has become slightly sick and has been absent from school this week."

You ask:

> is a sentence like 彼は風邪{かぜ}**が**体調を崩す correct to say that he is ill because of a cold?

No, it is not correct, grammatical or natural-sounding.  You can say instead:

> 「彼は風邪**で**体調を崩す。」

using a 「で」.

Comment: can you talk about why 崩す which Jirei describes as a transitive verb doesn't need a "doer" in 「彼は風邪で体調を崩す。」? Or is he/she wrong about what type of verb it is?  I am familiar with the pattern "Xで体調を崩す。" but I internalize such phrases "wholesale" so I don't understand what grammar point Jirei is trying to make.

Comment: ^ どこらへんがわかんないのかがわかんないです・・`why 崩す which Jirei describes as a transitive verb doesn't need a "doer"` <- doer は「彼」でしょう？ 彼は subject, 風邪で due to a cold, 体調を object, 崩す verb. 「崩す」はフツーに他動詞で・・　voluntary に、使役的・強制的に destroy って言うより、involuntary に、許可っていうか、「let ~ collapse」みたいな感じで。。。例えば「彼は財布を無くした」とか「彼は財布を落とした」とか、「彼はばくちで身を滅ぼした」とかと同じことだと思うんですけど・・